# Forward mails to mobile as an SMS

Tags: .net, gmail

I am trying to create an application, which send out an SMS as soon as you receive a mail in your email account. I have an SMS API, which will take care of sending the SMS to a particular mobile number. What I am now concerned is, how do I let my application know that a mail has been received. For simplicity sake I will be using the Gmail account. So as soon as I receive a mail on my Gmail id I want a sms to be sent to my mobile, which has the senders address as well as the subject.

Any suggestions as to how can i let my application know about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to poll Gmail from time to time. You can use IMAP or just parse [the feed provided by gmail](https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom).

See [this](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/faq.html#GmailAtomFeed)

> Does Gmail have a Data API?
>
> No, but you can use Gmail's Atom feed with AuthSub or OAuth to request
>   read-only access to a user's unread
>   messages. The scope should be set to
>   https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/

Comment: But i am making an asp.net application. this will be hosted on a server. how do i make it parse my gmail feed, say every 30 minutes?